# Angular input type submit don't prevent form submit on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, razor

All I want to accomplish is to show a "loading ..." when the submit button is clicked using AngularJS. 
I figured that should be quite easy using

```
<form ng-if="!export.buttonClicked">
   ... various input values without ng-model
   <input type="submit" value="Start export" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="export.buttonClicked=true;">
</form>
<div ng-if="export.buttonClicked">
   loading...
</div>
```

How could I be so wrong. **Seems like Angular prevents the default form submission like this. Showing the loading div works quite fine, but I need the form to be submitted (The server has to calculate a lot so it responds slowly and I would like to show loading... instead of the Button once it has been clicked)**

I can't use ng-submit because I have to combine AngularJS with Razor and I don't want no ng-form or ng-model...

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify what do you want to achieve; currently it's absolutely unclear.

Comment: If you don't want to leverage ng-form, ng-model, or ng-submit then what are you getting out of using Angular?  Just to show a "loading..." dialog?  Why not use straight js or jQuery?

Comment: @jbrown because it's an MVC application mixed with Angular and I do not want to mix in jQuery and it is considered an ugly thing to mix Angular with jQuery.

Comment: @Dmitriy Khudorozhkov what I want to achieve is stated quite clear in the first line of my question I think? Or what is unclear about that.... Anyhow, I extended the code a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: @Benedikt - right, I wasn't suggesting mixing jquery in with angular I was really questioning why you were including angular but reluctant to use it as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an angular controller tied to the page or div, just use a function in your `ng-click` like this:

```
<div ng-controller="sampleController" style="text-align:center">
    <button ng-click="buttonClickedFunction()">Submit</button>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</div>
```

Then in your controller:

```
yourAppName.controller('sampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.buttonClickedFunction = function() {
        $scope.message = "Loading...";
        // Whatever else you wish to do with your button/function.
    };
});
```

This puts loading on the screen once button is clicked, if this is what you were shooting to do?

Comment: Yes but at the same time the button has to be of type="submit" and submit the form which it is inside of.

Comment: @Benedikt you could also use https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy and pass in the $scope variable. place cg-busy in your form and append the necessary animation while you load. Otherwise, this can also be done via ajax call within Angular

Comment: I know about angular-busy and similar projects... I had just hoped there is a simple way to like stop Angular from preventing the form submit. Guess I really have to take the long road and do a $http request and adding ng-model to the input fields mapping them to Razor on initial load :( Thanks though!

Comment: @Benedikt No problem, if my answer has helped you in any way, upvote if possible :) I think there might be a simpler way of going about it, but I haven't researched myself.

Comment: Since no better solution was found I just had to do it as I feared with $http and mapping the fields. Although it's not what I was hoping for you still provided a solution so I marked it as accepted answer @NoReceipt4Panda